# Can I use both Shopify Polaris and React at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-api

I have already built the store using only Polaris. And now I want to build a custom landing page with React, can I both install React and keep using Polaris at the same time?

Or if I want to use React for my store, I need to develop a whole new storefront?

Comment: Yes, you can. Shopify Polaris is meant for building user interfaces for the Shopify apps, so that users face consistent UI inside their admin panel. You can use either Polaris / React for building a store

Comment: please share your code snippet to help others answer your question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

second, yes, you need to. And to get started and up and running quickly using [builder.io](https://github.com/BuilderIO/builder/tree/main/examples/react). They have SDK to build any custom storefront very fast.